# how to quick get current lat long from device GPS system

Tags: blackberry, gps, blackberry-storm, blackberry-os5, location-provider

My application is based on Event according to user current location. when i start my application Splash screen comes for 3 or 4 second .. then during splash screen i m getting current location of device and according to this current location i am displaying Event list..

But at the first time i m not able to get current location during the `splash screen` .after some time i am getting current location successfully for other screen.

In BB device there is GPS system and when we press device `Menu` key it will be refresh and get our current location. and it is display there. so is there any way to get quick current location from this GPS system (device system) which is displaying `Latitude` and `Longitude` there.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can get last know location which will be immediately. But who know how far user is now.
Cell tower method will be also quick. But it also is not accurate as you probably expected.
As I remember there is 30-80 secs while device gets accurate location (if it's possible).

So I would suggest you to use available location with less accuracy and update list as you get more accurate one.

Comment: Thanks @Eugen Martynov for reply. but i don't know how to get available location from the device GPS system ?

Comment: Look to the LocationProvider API